# Removing %2520 and other nonstandard characters from URL in obj c

Tags: php, ios, url, uiwebview

I am getting a URL from server and trying to load the URL in webview. The issue is that the url which I am getting contains non standard characters. The URL is:

```
https//p-r3.test.abc.com:443%2Ftablet%2Fjsp%2Fgift%2Fipad%2Fgifter%2FgitGiftList.jsp%3FregId%3D74500002%26filterBy%3DviewAll%26pageId%3DourGifty%26sort%3Dcategory%26groupBy%3Dcategory%26view%3Dlist%26categoryId%3D%26addCat%3Dcat100540004&amp;title=re%20-&amp;imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fm-r3-testy.tr.com%3A443%2Ftablet%2Fimages%2Ft_Full.jpg%3Fwid%3D300%26hei%3D300.
```

I need to remove characters like `%2520`, `%2F`, `%3D` and other non standard characters from the URL. Anyone has idea to remove this encoding.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: See @Kolink answer, and get your server team to fix the garbage URL they're sending you. You know the URL is encoded wrong when you're seeing `%2F` in place of `/` for the regular part of the URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%2520` is simply a double-encoded space. Encode it once and you get `%20`, encode it twice and you get `%2520`. It's not "non-standard", it's just poorly coded. In theory, there's no reason why you can't just replace `%2520` with a space, but for all I know the server-side code is *expecting* the double-encoded string.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.I am removing the encoding using the built in function of iOS.`abc = [def stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

and i am loading abc in webview.It is working fine.
Thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an urlencode() too many, or an urldecode() too few, in the code processing the URL server side.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple encoding, Remove any encoding first

```
   _pdfUrl = [ _pdfUrl stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];        
   _pdfUrl = [_pdfUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```